# Get a list of all users who sign-in in my application and record it in my database

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, uid

I have a project that create a one-to-one chat app. I followed [this guide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#8). I tried to get the user's UID when they signed in to my friendly-chat web app, but it doesn't work in my database.

Code:

```js
function initFirebaseAuth() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(authStateObserver);
    firebase.firestore().collection("user").add({
        user: user.uid
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error writing new user to Firebase Database', error);
    });
}
```

Comment: does that code add a user to the database? is there an error shown somewhere in some console or other? "it don't work" isn't a clear problem statement

Comment: sorry, it don't add any user in my database, and don't have any error in console. But i write it in the saveMessages() functions, it work! and add uid user when they sent their message. But i don't want record when send message, i want when sign-in because it reducts the coincidence of uid and more reasonable

Comment: no idea how any of that comment relates to the code you posted, sorry